# excel vba coding for data entry

Tags: excel, vba, forms

Im new in coding. I have an Excel file with 2 sheets. `Sheet1` is data entry, and `sheet2` database. In `sheet1` I have 4 variables: `Id`, `Name`, `Old`, `Email`. And I want to use ActiveX control (command button).

I want when I fill the data in `sheet1` and press the button it should copy the data to the `sheet2` (image below showing `sheet2`), also if I want to fill another data it should go down 2 rows for new data (as row 9 in image). Thanks for helping.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim iRow As Long  
    iRow = Sheets(2).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
       .Range("A" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("A5").Value
       .Range("A" & iRow + 1).Value = Sheet1.Range("A6").Value
       .Range("B" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("B5").Value
       .Range("B" & iRow + 1).Value = Sheet1.Range("B6").Value
       .Range("C" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("C5").Value
       .Range("C" & iRow + 1).Value = Sheet1.Range("C6").Value
       .Range("D" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("D5").Value
       .Range("D" & iRow + 1).Value = Sheet1.Range("D5").Value          
    End With

    Call Reset
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, so please include what you have tried in your question, and explain where you ran into trouble.

Comment: @braX I add my code to the question

Comment: `iRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` then `If iRow <> 5 Then iRow = iRow + 2`

Comment: Note that `Sheet2` is not necessarily `Sheets(2)`. Make sure you understand the difference between `Sheets(2)` (the sheet in tab **position** 2) and `Sheets("Sheet2")` (the sheet with the **tab** name "Sheet2") and `Sheet2` (the sheet with the **VBA** name "Sheet2"). They *can* be 3 totally different sheets, as they can easily get moved around and because there exist 2 naming systems (tab name vs. VBA name) that are not linked in any way.

Comment: @TimWilliams it show error message: Compile error: Expected end of statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vba
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim iRow As Long  
    iRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 
    If iRow <> 5 Then iRow = iRow + 2  'add two rows if not first dataset

    '...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but for first dataset it is start 2 row down, I mean as image it should start in row 5, but it started in row 7